# Rendering a dynamically loaded React component

Tags: reactjs, import, lazy-loading, code-splitting

`Here is my attempt to dynamically load a component at the click of a button, and show on page.
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-haze-knste?file=/src/App.tsx

I am using the below line of code to dynamically import the component when button is clicked.

`const importedComponent = React.lazy(() => import("./DynamicallyImportedComponent"));`

And the state is set using

```
this.setState({
      importModule: importedComponent
      // importModule: CommonEditorCallout
    });
```

However, this does not render correctly.

When I use the regular import using the below, it renders fine

`import DynamicallyImportedComponent from "./DynamicallyImportedComponent";`

Is this possibly due to the fact that in the regular import I specify the name of the component I am importing, or something to do with the dynamic import itself?

Answer (score 0):

[Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy)

> The lazy component should then be rendered inside a Suspense component, which allows us to show some fallback content (such as a loading indicator) while we’re waiting for the lazy component to load.

So wrapping your lazy loaded component with `React.Suspense` with a `fallback` props will fix the error.

```
 <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
   {this.state.showImportedModule && <div>{<ComponentToShow />}</div>}
 </React.Suspense>
```

See [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-shape-i0uiz?file=/src/App.tsx)